# Aspera:Error: internal error - unable to start token generation

Tags: curl

While i was uploading a file on aspera using curl command,Server responded with the following error:
Error: internal error - unable to start token generation

Curl Command:
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:3000/upload -d '{ "transfer_requests" : [ { "transfer_request" : { "paths" : [{}],"destination_root" : "/" } } ] }'

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify encryption token in opt/aspera/etc/aspera.conf:
Follow this Link:
 https://download.asperasoft.com/download/docs/csrv/3.4.5/osx/html/index.html?https://download.asperasoft.com/download/docs/csrv/3.4.5/osx/html/fasp/http-fallback.html